# Error while creating flow for external services

Tags: schema, external-services

I am trying to pull information from the Editorial Manager API and sync it with Salesforce records but I'm having trouble. I wrote a custom schema and also finished a flow. I am getting an error when I run the flow. I'm wondering if this issue is a result of the schema being incorrect or an issue with my flow? Attached are the screenshots of the error and the flow.

[image]

[image]